Factoring separated polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$
I find a problem:
Let's called polynomial $P\in \mathbb{C}[x, y]$ separated if exist polynomials $Q$ and $R$ with $$P(x, y) = Q(x) + R(y).$$
Is that true that in a factorization of a separated polynomial $P$ into irreducible polynomials one of them is also separated?
How to use irreducibility of factors in this problem? (I can't solve this problem yet and irreducibility is the only thing I don't know how to use.)

I think I find a counterexample as follows:
$$ (2x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + 2x + y )(2x^2 - 2xy + y^2 + 2x - y )=4x^4 + y^4 + 8x^3 + 4x^2 - y^2$$
(I construct this example with the help of Maple, considering the product of 2 conics and using Groebner basis to construct the coefficients.)
One can show these factors are irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ by applying:
Theorem: A conic $ax+by+cx^2+dxy+ey^2$ is degenerated in $\mathbb{C}$, iff
$$ \begin{vmatrix} 2c & d & a\\
d & 2e & b\\
a & b & 0
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Hi, I have corrected my answer. Hope this time it is right.
